# grafana variables dynamically changing mysql

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to add dropdowns (grafana variables) in my dashboard that changes dynamically. This what I tried

1. Created variable named Domain
   Query : `select fields_Domain from launcher_dropdown;`
   Output: "ABC ESG"
2. Created variable named Project( changes dynamically based on Domain value)
   Query : `select fields_Project from launcher_dropdown where fields_Domain in($Domain)` ( also tried =$Domain)
   But here I am getting error 
   Since I am new in Grafana finding it difficult.I am following Grafana [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/mysql/#using-variables-in-queries) . But no luck.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out variable should be inside single quotes `''`

E.g. `select fields_Project from launcher_dropdown where fields_Domain ='$Domain'`